building pybind11 package that wraps .so file with Rye and setuptools
I try to build a python package that wraps C++ code. I use pybind11 to create the necessary bindings. I manage the project using Rye with setuptools instead of the default hatchlings as build system (because the pybind11 docs use setuptools).
I have a few (probably related) problems.:
When I build my project, the resulting dist/minimal_example-0.1.0-cp312-cp312-linux_x86_64.whl does contain a .so file, but dist/minimal_example-0.1.0.tar.gz doesn't.
When I import the .so file I can use and see the add() function
cd  /dist
unzip *.whl minimal_example.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

>>> import minimal_example
>>> minimal_example.__file__
'/home/me/minimal_example/dist/minimal_example.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
>>> minimal_example.add(1,2)
3

when use python in the project dir or with rye run python I can't access functions from the .so file.
>>> import minimal_example
>>> minimal_example.__file__
'/home/me/minimal_example/src/minimal_example/__init__.py'
>>> minimal_example.add(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'minimal_example' has no attribute 'add

I have two questions.

how can I configure my build in such a way that minimal_example.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so is available in dist/minimal_example-0.1.0.tar.gz?
How can I configure Rye in such a way that it can access the .so file it builds.

My suspicion is that I need to put the .so file in src/minimal_example/ during the build, and that this will solve both problems. Is this correct? And can somebody guide me in configuring setuptools/Rye to do this?
recreate minimal project
See the code to recreate a minimal example.
export PROJECTDIR=${PWD}
# I don't have clang available on my system so I use cc
export CC=cc
export CXX=c++
rye init minimal_example
cd minimal_example

./.python-version
3.12.2

./pyproject.toml
[project]
name = "minimal-example"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Add your description here"
authors = [
    { name = "me", email = "me@email.com" }
]
dependencies = [
    "pybind11>=2.12.0",
    "setuptools>=70.0.0",
]
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">= 3.8"

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "pybind11>=2.6.1"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.rye]
managed = true
dev-dependencies = []

./src/minimal_example/minimal_example.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(minimal_example, m) {
    m.doc() = "minimal docs";

    m.def("add", &add, "example add");
}

/.setup.py
from glob import glob
import os
from setuptools import setup

from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext

if (projectdir := os.environ.get("PROJECTDIR", None)) is None:
    raise ValueError("env PROJECTDIR not set.")

ext_modules = [
        Pybind11Extension(
            'minimal_example',
            sorted(glob('src/minimal_example/*.cpp')),
            extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-Wall', '-std=c++11', '-fPIC']
        )
    ]

setup(
     cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext}, ext_modules=ext_modules
)

